# google +1 like polling system

Tags: plugins, poll

I have a photography blog - and in a monthly post i feature different images for different photographers - around 50+ pic and I ask the users to vote for their favorite picture.

It is turning out hard - since it is really hard to make up mind about one picture - so instead, i'd like to implement a polling system that is pretty much like google's +1

Each image will have a +1 button near it - if you like the pic, you click +1 - you can like many pics.

There is no social media interactions going in the background - like no real submission of photos to google+1 to avoid spamming users.. but it is just the idea.

I do not want to use regular poll with a checkbox.

Is there any plugin that does something close to this? any feedback or idea on how to go around coding it?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: please go back to your old questions and accept some answers, it's the least you can do to thank the people who give you the time and answered.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial http://bavotasan.com/2009/simple-voting-for-wordpress-with-php-and-jquery/ and its follow up http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-better-voting-system-for-wordpress/

which shows a simple implementation of a vote like system.